# Service Layer Implementation Ideas with MVC4 Application

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.NET MVC4 web application with the following layers.

1. Domain Objects
2. Business
3. Data Access
4. ASP.NET MVC4 Web

One more layer need to be added for consuming the application as a service to be accessed by Android Application.

1. Which one will be better to create a web service? MVC4 Web API or WCF?

Better Ideas are welcomed!

Comment: Downvoters, care to comment. Whats wrong with the question? One Easy Click Can Downvote, but don't ever do that without proper comments, so that it will be useful to write better questions in future

Comment: I would say WebAPI. If you know ASP.NET MVC, then you can get started quickly with WebAPI and because it makes use of HTTP, then its also easy to consume in different clients.